# how can i remap <C-w>{number}h to <C-w>{number}j

Tags: key-bindings, map-operator

I am trying to remap my `hjkl` keys to `jklö`. this is not a problem in most simple cases, but with commands like `<C-w>h` where you can specify an amount in the form of `<C-w>{count}h` or `{count}<C-w>h` this doesn't seem to work.

is there some way of doing a mapping like

```
nn <C-w>{count}j <C-w>{count}h
```

Comment: You might need langmap, but im not an expert there

Comment: @D.BenKnoble that does seem to work. i just used `set langmap+=jklöJKLé;hjklHJKL`

Comment: Feel free to self-answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

what worked for me was to use langmap.

```
set langmap=jklöJKLé;hjlkHJKL
```

this remaps the keys for all commands

Answer (score 0):

Note that the correct way to type this command is `{count}<C-w>h`, with the `{count}` preceding the command. `<C-w>h` (and its friends) is a whole command on its own, so the count should precede it and not stand in the middle of the command.

And note that the following mapping:

```
nnoremap <C-w>j <C-w>h
```

will work for both `<C-w>j` and `{count}<C-w>j`.

But there are workarounds you can use.

Assuming it's unlikely you'll want to switch a double digit number of windows in any direction at any time, you could simply add mappings for single digit counts:

```
nnoremap <C-w>1j 1<C-w>h
nnoremap <C-w>2j 2<C-w>h
nnoremap <C-w>3j 3<C-w>h
nnoremap <C-w>4j 4<C-w>h
nnoremap <C-w>5j 5<C-w>h
nnoremap <C-w>6j 6<C-w>h
nnoremap <C-w>7j 7<C-w>h
nnoremap <C-w>8j 8<C-w>h
nnoremap <C-w>9j 9<C-w>h
```

You *could* keep going. And you could generate these programatically using a for loop as well...

If you want a more general solution than that, consider creating an `<expr>` mapping for `<C-w>` itself, which will read more characters (using [`getchar()`](https://vimhelp.org/eval.txt.html#getchar%28%29)), parse a `{count}` and a remaining command, mapping the "hjkl" commands according to your specification and issuing the final remapped command including the `{count}`. (Personally, I think that's overkill, but go for it if you feel like it!)